# Anova tree and Class rpart

Tags: r, anova, rpart

I am trying to find cut points by using rpart fucntion and my response variable is binary. When I use anova method, it gives a set of separation, while when I use class method I can get nothing. Can anyone tell me why is that and the separation by anova is still a good cut for binary variable or not?
Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

The problem you are having is that ANOVA is for regressions with a binary independent variable, think of a logit model. Classification is more like an OLS regression where the independent variable doesn't have to be 1 or 0. You are getting null on a class because it is the wrong method.

hope that helps.